# How to configure solr search only for a branch of pages in Typo3?

Tags: solr, typo3

I configured solr search for typo3. I want to search only certain branch of pages. Now i got search result from all pages.

I want to get search result only from one branch of the page.

How to achieve this ?

Comment: How do you import the pages into solr from typo3? Is there a plugin or are you using DataImportHandler?

Answer (score 0):

Within the typoscript setup you can set

```
config.index_enable = 0
```

to disable indexing for all the sub pages (see [solr at forge](http://forge.typo3.org/projects/extension-solr/wiki/Setup_the_Solr_Extension#Typoscript-38-Backend-Settings))